# Xcode OSX Server "Error creating bot"

Tags: xcode, osx-server

Xcode 7.3.1, OSX server 5.1

When I create a bot, it will pop "Error creating bot: Could not perform request because the database produced and error:{exit_status,1}"

Comment: Exactly. What is the problem?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I always stuck in `Integration(step 9 of 9) Uploading results` and I can not cancel it. If I want to run another Integration, the error happened.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk To solve this problem, the only way I can do is just delete Xcode Server's Database. After deleting the Database I can create a new bot and Integration it, however, It stuck in the step 9 again. If I run a new simple project created by Xcode default Single View Project it works well.

Comment: How to delete server database? Where it is located?

Comment: /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Database

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I saw you asked another question about bot failure,  have you solved it?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my machine and reinstalled xcode server It helped. Do not know the reason.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message getting started, but deleting the database by itself didn't fix this issue.  I'd recommend trying to reset Xcode Server.

**WARNING: this will delete your bots and integration data.**

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset.
```

Here's a link to where I found my fix.
https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-05-04-under-the-hood-of-xcode-server/